# Is there any service in AWS IOT which is similar to that of "Device Provisioning Service"(DPS) in Azure IOT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Is there any service in AWS IOT which is similar to that of "Device Provisioning Service"(DPS) in Azure IOT ?
If similar service is not available,any ideas how it can be achieved.
I am thinking of the following steps:
1.Configure a custom end point(global) in AWS IOT
2.Connect device with this custom end point
3.Once connection with custom end point is successful,
Provide the device with relevant IOT core end-point based on its location attribute,Load Key and certificate on the device
4.Now device can connect with relevant IOT core end-point using loaded key and certificate
But custom end point is currently supported in us-east-1 region only And incase of AWS IOT core in a region is down ,how to achieve cross region aws iot core connection.

Answer (score 0):

the aws's registerThing operation from:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html#registerThing-property

```
var params = {
  templateBody: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  parameters: {
    '<Parameter>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<Parameter>': ... */
  }
};
iot.registerThing(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

the above is a nodejs code snipet with the same functionality as azure's provisioning service:

```
 var serviceClient = provisioningServiceClient.fromConnectionString(this.connectionString);

                var enrollment = {
                    registrationId: id,
                    deviceId: id,
                    attestation: {
                        type: 'x509',
                        x509: {
                            clientCertificates: {
                                primary: {
                                    certificate: certificate
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                serviceClient.createOrUpdateIndividualEnrollment(enrollment as IndividualEnrollment, function (err, enrollmentResponse) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('error creating the individual enrollment: ' + err);
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("enrollment record returned: " + JSON.stringify(enrollmentResponse, null, 2));
                        resolve(enrollmentResponse);
                    }
                });
```